# I want to copy folder EXCLUDING those with certain folder names

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a folder called "Testnames" and within that two folders called "Bunny, Bugs_" and "Lightyear, Buzz".

Using the command:

```psh
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\Testnames -Recurse -Exclude '_'
```

I get:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         10/9/2015  11:43 AM            Lightyear, Buzz
```

Perfect!

However when I use the command:

```psh
Copy-Item C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\Testnames -Exclude '_' -Recurse C:\Users\Galen\Testfolder
```

Both Bug's and Buzz's folders are copied into `Testfolder`. What change do I need to implement to **only** copy Buzz's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Run `Get-ChildItem` without the parameter `-Recurse` to get the root folders. Filter that list for items that don't have an underscore in their name. Then copy the remaining items recursively.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\Testnames' |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*_*' } |
  Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\Galen\Testfolder' -Recurse
```

Comment: Can I ask what the quotes around C:\... after GCI and CI do? Why do I need them in this instance when I haven't used them before without issue? I'm not trying to be snarky I'm just very new to this!

Comment: @GalenHench Single and double quotes define strings. PowerShell sometimes treats stuff as a string even without the quotes, but I prefer being on the safe side. If your path contains spaces you must use quotes anyway.